# how to join tow combobox data

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, combobox

i have two combo box one and data load from two different table  first combobox  code is

```
>  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select empno,ename from emp", con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                combobox1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());

            }
```

Result:

```
KING

BLAKE

CLARK
```

and  second combobox code is

```
> OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select UnitId,UnitName from
> TableUnit", con);
>             OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
>             while (dr1.Read())
>             {
>                 combobox2.Items.Add(dr1[1].ToString());
>             }
```

result:

```
ACCOUNTING

RESEARCH

SALES

OPERATIONS
```

how can i have load data join both  result (combobox1+combobox2) to combobox3 such as

```
KING  ACCOUNTING

BLAKE RESEARCH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two combobox content in third combobox in following way :

```
for (int i = 0; i < (combobox1.Items.Count < combobox2.Items.Count ? combobox1.Items.Count : combobox2.Items.Count); i++)
{
       combobox3.Items.Add($"{combobox1.Items[i]} {combobox2.Items[i]}");
}
```